# Huge memory usage - can't find source of issue

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments, nszombie

When tracking zombies in my app using instruments, almost immediately after the app starts, the number of live bites increases at a very rapid rate. The responsible caller for this memory usage is `-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]`. What does this mean? I have made no direct calls to this method in my code. Below is a screenshot of instruments showing this problem.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view in instruments to the "Call Tree" rather than the Statistics - this will show you the hierarchy of calls being made so that you can track which method ends up issuing this call.

Comment: Very helpful, I haven't used instruments much as you may have noticed. Thanks alot!